# Await async firebase foreach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to wait for the getAnswers value response from firebase and push it in the foreach array ! how can i do that ?

```
 async fetchData() {
    console.log('fetchdata')
    const UID = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const ref = FirebaseRef.child('my_questions/' + UID + '/');
    // console.log(ref);
    ref
      .orderByKey()
      .limitToLast(this.state.limit)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        var items = [];
        snapshot.forEach(child => {

          var getAnswers = await FirebaseRef.child('counter/questions/' + child.key + '/count_answers').once('value')



          items.push({
            key: child.key,
            ...child.val(),
            count_answers: getAnswers
          });


        });



})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` and `.map` instead of `forEach`:

```
const items = await Promise.all(snapshot.map(async (child) => {
  const getAnswers = await Firebase...
  ...

  return {
    key: child.key,
    ...child.val(),
    count_answers: getAnswers
  }
}))
```

See this answer for more detail: [Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map#40140562)

Comment: Since when do firebase snapshots support `map`?

Comment: @Bergi Interesting... when I wrote this answer I didn't realize `snapshot` is a Firebase-specific data collection, I assumed this person was working with an array. Given that, I'm a little surprised this was marked as the correct answer, but you're right. `snapshot` doesn't support `map`.