# How to wait for a promise to resolve inside a map?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of objects that I want to process. The object is passed to a promise function that does this and that and resolves back. The process could be instant or not, based on previously cached value. If there is already calculated value, it will resolve to it instantly. Else, it will calculate. Now the issue I am having is that the next object is passed to the promise before the first object's status is calcualted:

```
   let people = [ 
                {groupId: 1, name: 'Jessica Coleman', status: 'Unknown', id:1}
                {groupId: 1, name: 'Eric Tomson', status: 'Unknown', id:2}
                {groupId: 1, name: 'Samuel Bell', status: 'Unknown', id:3}

      ];
```

now I want to absolutely wait for the promise to resolve during loop even if the promise takes a minute to calculate on the very instance. All people with the same group have the same status. Hence, the promise checks if a group has already been calculated. If yes, returns it. Else, it calculates. and that's where the issue lies. Before Jessica 1 is finished, the other people are passed.

```
    people.map(function(person) {
   // return the promise to array
   this.calculatorService
    .getStatus(person)
    .then(function(res) {
      person.status = res;


    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map)

Answer (score 31):

Array iterators like `map` or `forEach` don't work with promises because they don't know how to await a result. Use a simple `for` loop instead:

```
for (let person of people)
  person.status = await this.calculatorService.getStatus(person)
```

If you really want a "functional" way (and avoid explicit async/await), you can define a function similar to the bluebird's [`Promise.each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html):

```
Promise.each = function(ary, fn) {
    return ary.reduce((p, x) => p.then(() => fn(x)), Promise.resolve(null))
}
```

and apply it like this:

```
function setStatus(person) {
    return calculatorService
        .getStatus(person)
        .then(res => person.status = res);
}

Promise.each(people, setStatus).then(...)
```

Comment: where would the async be in that case since await cant work in non-async functions?

Comment: @WedeAsmeraTseada The function that contains this loop construct needs to be marked `async`.

Answer (score 7):

Make it work synchronously with `async/await`. (`for..of` would be better suited than `.map` in this case btw).

```js
for (let person of people) {
   person.status = await this.calculatorService.getStatus(person);
})
```

Comment: I'd recommend you never use `.forEach` for asynchronous work since there's no way to actually await until the loop finishes. A [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or a simple `for` loop is far more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
let people = [ 
  {groupId: 1, name: 'Jessica Coleman', status: 'Unknown', id:1},
  {groupId: 1, name: 'Eric Tomson', status: 'Unknown', id:2},
  {groupId: 1, name: 'Samuel Bell', status: 'Unknown', id:3}
];


for (let person of people) {
  await this.calculatorService.getStatus(person).then(res => {
    person.status = res;
  });
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in your `Array.map`; even if you did, you can't eventually wait for an `Array.map` to finish async work. Also this is far more convoluted than it needs to be. Why are you wrapping a `Promise` in another `Promise`?

Comment: Yes it is convoluted but it is working as expected, I edited my answer now i am returning a updated value. thanks for pointing out my mistake :)

Comment: All the mistakes I pointed out in my first comment are still there. You're also using `Array.map` as a loop. It's not really mapping anything.

Comment: You don't need to wrap `this.calculatorService.getStatus(person)` in another `Promise`. I'll edit your answer myself so I can show you.

Comment: but then it will wont work as far as i know we need to return the promise or we have to return promise in `this.calculatorService.getStatus()` function.

Comment: then your way is valid :)

Comment: here's an example of it working using a mock `getStatus` function: https://jsfiddle.net/ruegzowy/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function:

```js
let people = [ 
    {groupId: 1, name: 'Jessica Coleman', status: 'Unknown', id:1},
    {groupId: 1, name: 'Eric Tomson', status: 'Unknown', id:2},
    {groupId: 1, name: 'Samuel Bell', status: 'Unknown', id:3}
];

function recCalculatorService(people) {
    if (!people || !people.length) {
        return;
    }
    this.calculatorService
        .getStatus(people.shift())
        .then(function(res) {
            person.status = res;
            recCalculatorService(people);
        });
}

// use people.slice() if you want to keep people array intact
recCalculatorService(people);
```