# Mapping an Array to another Array with an Inner Subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of Objects, we'll say it's off type `Objects[]`.

I need to map each Object to another type of Object, eg, `DestinationObject[]` however there is a property on `DestinationObject[]` that I need to look in Firebase for so I'll need to do a subscribe, or a `pipe(map())`.

Unfortunately if I do a Subscribe, I get returned a Subscription, and if I do a `pipe(map())` I get an list of Observables, rather an Observable List of Objects (ie I want `Observable<Object[]>` and not `Observable<Object>[]`

Here's the code:

```
  processUsers(users: Users[], groupUsers: Users[]): Observable<MappedUser[]> {
    return groupUsers.map(groupUser => {
      return this.firebaseService.SubscribableFunction(groupUser.id).pipe(map(array => {
        return {
          name: groupUser.name,
          arrayLength: array.length,
        } as MappedUser;
      }));
    });
  }
```

So two simple array objects, we do get a MappedUser returned, but because of the pipe(map()) on the SubscribableFunction, that returns an Observable and therefore the map on the first line returns a list of Observable. Which wasn't quite what I wanted.

Do you have any solutions? I've tried map, mergeMap, from() of() but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Update
Here's the subscribable function as requested:

```
  SubscribableFunction(userId: string): Observable<Equipment[]> {
    const collection = this.afs.collection<Equipment>('equipment', ref => ref.where('userId', '==', userId));
    return collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(items => {
      return items.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data(),
        } as Equipment;
      });
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Once you've mapped the source array to an array of observables, you'd end with something like `[obs1, obs2, obs3, ...]`. So here you could use RxJS `forkJoin` function to trigger all the observables in parallel and get the results as an array of objects.

Try the following

```js
processUsers(users: Users[], groupUsers: Users[]): Observable<MappedUser[]> {
  return forkJoin(groupUsers.map(groupUser => { // <-- return `forkJoin` here
    return this.firebaseService.SubscribableFunction(groupUser.id).pipe(map(array => {
      return {
        name: groupUser.name,
        arrayLength: array.length,
      } as MappedUser;
    }));
  }));
}
```

Now you could subscribe to the function

```js
processUsers(...).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res), // would log `[{MappedUser}, {MappedUser}, {MappedUser},... ],
  err => // good practice to handle HTTP errors
);
```

Note: RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) will only emit when all the input observables complete. If you wish to have a stream of data from the observables, you could look into `zip` or `combineLatest`. You could find the differences between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990).

Comment: Thanks Michael. That didn't appear to work. Not sure what's going on, but putting some logging in, I see that each groupUser from the map is processed, then all the observables from the SubscribableFunction get output, but I actually get no output on the processUsers.subscribe()

Comment: @Simon: Did you try a `console.log` in the error callback? The observable wouldn't emit if even one of the observable errors out.

Comment: Unfortunately no errors. Tried converting this to a Promises, but just get back a List of Promises.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Could you please show the implementation of `this.firebaseService.SubscribableFunction()`? Based on it's name and nature I assume it returns an observable.

Comment: Some further reading of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137483/how-to-wait-for-a-promise-to-resolve-inside-a-map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map potentially highlights the problem. They say "Array iterators like map or forEach don't work with promises because they don't know how to await a result. Use a simple for loop instead:", I know that's about promises, but I remember you can't explicitly return a value from a subscribe as it's asynchronous. Sadly, I think I know what I need to do now.

Comment: That's why I didn't convert it to promises. Theoretically the solution should work. But I'm not familiar with Firestore and I'm not sure what's going wrong here.