# Return resolved promise

Tags: promise, strapi, resolve

I have a function in my strapi where I map the data and run another query inside.

```
async search(ctx) {
    const authors = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "author 1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "author 2"
        },
    ]

    authors.map((data, i) => {
        var books = this.getBooks(data.id)
        console.log(books)

        // some stuffs here
    })
},

getBooks: async function (authorId) {
    return await strapi.query('books').find({ userId: authorId })
}
```

The `console.log('books')` display `Promise { <pending> }`. I'm not very familiar with the promise stuff but I tried something like below but guess it's not the right way. It's still returning the same promise pending.

```
getBooks: async function (authorId) {
    const books = await strapi.query('books').find({ userId: authorId })
    return Promise.resolve(books)
}
```

Comment: try returning just books in getBooks function.

Comment: If I return just books, that has no difference with the original function I have in the first code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137483/how-to-wait-for-a-promise-to-resolve-inside-a-map#answer-59137767) . It appears that `map` doesn't work with promises. I switched to `for` loop as mentioned in the discussion and it's working now.

```
async search(ctx) {
    const authors = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "author 1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "author 2"
        },
    ]

    for (let data of authors) {
        const books = await strapi.query('books').find({ userId: data.id })
        console.log(books)

        // some stuffs here
    }
}
```