# Wait for map to finish running to execute final call

Tags: javascript

As the questions says I'm trying to wait for a map to finish executing before I run another command.  In this case console log. I have

```
let concernsInDB = [];
let ctr = 0;

    this.state.templateOptions.map(el => {
      el.details.map(elDetail => {
        this.getConcernsDB(elDetail.values)
        .then(elDetailResults => {
          let detailsToPush = {};
          if(elDetailResults.length) {
            detailsToPush[elDetailResults[0].value_id] = elDetailResults;
            concernsInDB.push(detailsToPush);
          }
        })
      })
    })
    console.log(concernsInDB);
```

The above code executes and I get a console.log of Array [].  The console.log is resolving before all other methods are finished.

this.state.templateOptions contains an array of several objects (about 50, so I'm not putting all here):

```
 Object {
    "active": 1,
    "id": 1378,
    "name": "Wires are running through trees",
    "narrative": "Service drop wires are running through tree(s).It is recommended to have a contacting utility company or a qualified electrician and/or tree s",vice company to correct conditions as necessary.
    "value_id": 13935,
  },
```

As I loop through them I run this method: `this.getConcernsDB(elDetail.values)`
elDetail.values is the "value_id" from the above example.  I then wait for it to resolve .then push the results into concernsInDB.  This has to be done on several records.  How would I wait for it all to finish before console.logging concernsInDB so it'll have all the completed data?

If I wrap it in a promise the resolve would run on each loop so I don't see how I could accomplish it.  Any solutions?

Comment: why are you using `.map` if you never return anything in the callbacks? you may as well use `.forEach` ... however, to do what you want, you actually WANT to use `.map` - but then don't IGNORE the returned value

Comment: Look into using `async` and `await` keywords. For example, if your `.forEach` (per Jaromanda X's suggestion) is inside an asyncronous function, you would be able to do something as simple as `let detailResults = await this.getConcernsDB(...)`.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown If there is no requirement for the order of execution, `Promise.all` is the superior choice.

Comment: There are many articles and questions on async operations and map e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map

Comment: @Amandan Promise.all only works with an array/iterable of promises are passed -- I was trying to build off of Jaromanda's `.forEach` comment. If OP sticks with `map`, then yes, Promise.all is definitely the go-to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Promise.all (twice) to wait for all the Promise based asynchrony to finish

You also want to return something in `.map` otherwise you'd use `.forEach` (.map is the correct method in this case though)

```
let concernsInDB = [];
let ctr = 0;

Promise.all(this.state.templateOptions.map(el => 
    Promise.all(el.details.map(elDetail => 
        this.getConcernsDB(elDetail.values)
        .then(elDetailResults => {
            let detailsToPush = {};
            if (elDetailResults.length) {
                detailsToPush[elDetailResults[0].value_id] = elDetailResults;
                concernsInDB.push(detailsToPush);
            }
        })
    ))
)).then(() => {
    console.log(concernsInDB);
});
```