# consistency using async await with map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have big chunk of array of object. I want to get something then assign it to a new property, I did this

```
async function t() {
  return bigChunkArr.map(async o => ({
    ...o,
    address: await getAddress(o.lat, o.lng)
  }))
}
const result = await t() //expected to be array
```

The problem the `result` is still a `promise`, why?

Comment: `result` would be an array, no way `result` is a promise, since `array.map` always returns an array - also, the `const result = await t();` code must by in an `async` function - otherwise the code woudn't run **at all**

Comment: also, no point in `async function t()` since you don't `await` in `t()`

Comment: Is this an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map

Comment: please use `for loop` instead of `map`.

Comment: @NarendraChouhan - that would make the calls to getAddress run in series rather than potentially parallel

Answer (score 1):

Map here will return an array of promises. We can use `Promise.all` to get the result of these promises when the return. In the code below, `t` will return a promise.

```
const t = () => {
    const promises = bigChunkArr.map(async (o) => {
        return {
            ...o,
            address: await getAddress(o.lat, o.lng)
        }
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```