# Type 'Promise<UserDomain>[]' is not assignable to type 'UserrDomain[]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm stuck in `async` hell:

```js
function convertToDomainUsers(dbUsers: Array<UserDB>): Array<UserDomain> {

  // iterate each DB user and convert them to domain user types
  const domainUsers: Array<UserDomain> = dbUsers.map( async (dbUser: UserDB) => {

    // first convert the DB user to a Domain User
    const domainUser: UserDomain = newUserDomainModel(dbUser);

    // Now we need to get their user links from the DB
    const dbUserLinks: Array<UserLinkDB> = await findDBUserLinks(dbUser.user_id);

    // convert their user links to Domain user links
    const domainUserLinks: Array<UserLinkDomain> = convertToUserLinks(dbUserLinks);

    // now merry up the domain user links to the domain user  
    domainUser.links = domainUserLinks;

    return domainUser;
  });

  return domainUsers;
}

function newUserDomainModel(user: UserDB): UserDomain {
  const domainUser: UserDomain = {
    username: user.user_username,
    firstName: user.user_name_first,
    lastName: user.user_name_last
  };
    
  return domainUser;
}

async function findDBUserLinks(userId: bigint): Promise<Array<UserLinkDB>> {
  const dbUserLinks: Array<UserLinkDB> = await getUserLinks(userId);
  return dbUserLinks;
}

async function getUserLinks(id: bigint): Promise<Array<UserLinkDB>> {
  setDB();
  await client.connect();

  const query = `
    select 
      link_url,
      social_type_id
    from user_links
    WHERE user_id = ${id}`;

  const res = await client.query(query);
  const links: Array<UserLinkDB> = res.rows;

  return Promise.resolve(links);
}
```

Error (happening on `const domainUsers:` in the `convertToDomainUsers` function):

```js
TS2322: Type 'Promise<UserDomain>[]' is not assignable to type 'UserDomain[]'.   Type 'Promise<UserDomain>' is missing the following properties from type 'UserDomain': username, firstName, lastName, fullName, and 6 more
```

comments were added for the sake of making this stack post easier to follow. I don't normally write comments, they're cruft.

Comment: Is `UserrDomain` with 2 "r" at the end of "User" a mistake?  I don't know if that's the actual issue, but it seems wrong.

Comment: sorry let me fix that, a paste error

Comment: Also, `dbUsers.map(async () => {})` is going to return a `Promise<Array<UserDomain>>` since anything returned by an `async` function will be wrapped in a `Promise`.  So `convertToDomainUsers`'s return type is incorrect.

Comment: @zero298 actually `Array<Promise<UserDomain>>`, it's an array of promises not a promise of an array.

Comment: And if you want to resolve an array of promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all. `convertToDomainUsers` will also have to return a promise, you can't magically make it synchronous at that point.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oops, yes got that inverted.

Comment: errr, ok I think I see now, what a pain.  I don't know if there's an easier way to go about this, but don't think so when dealing with making calls within a map like this.  I thought I could somehow get out of async and yield better and make it cleaner but you really can't here

Comment: It's still much less of a pain than `.then()` callbacks nested 6 deep.

Comment: agree, definitely less pain.  I guess mapping DB entities to Domain entities is just not a lot of fun :).  I could have also doin joins in my query but I hate that.  Would rather just get the child data via separate calls and merry up at the end for a complex type like this

Comment: Are you just missing an await - the map function is async.  So should it be const domainUsers: Array<UserDomain> = await dbUsers.map ...

Comment: @Woody no, you can't just await an Array.map

Comment: Woody:  I do have an async inside the map `await findDBUserLinks`

Comment: Right - so the problem is that an async function automatically wraps the return value in a Promise.  So you are mapping into an Array of promises just like the compiler is telling you. So you will have to then await all those promises.

Comment: @PositiveGuy yes, the callbacks are async, that's what's making it an array of promises. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40140149/3001761, you can't just await the array .map returns.

Comment: just trying to figure outnow how to promise.all on it.  So the caller `const domainUsers = convertToDomainUsers(dbUsers);`

Comment: thanks, much @jonrsharpe my head hurts.  `await Promise.all(...)`

Comment: await Promise.all(dbUsers.map(...) should do it I think

Answer (score 0):

**Calling:**

```
const domainUsers = await Promise.all(convertToDomainUsers(dbUsers));
```

**Working implementation:**

```
function convertToDomainUsers(dbUsers: Array<UserDB>): Array<Promise<UserDomain>> {

  const domainUsers: Array<Promise<UserDomain>> = dbUsers.map( async (dbUser: UserDB) => {

    const domainUser: UserDomain = newUserDomainModel(dbUser);

    const dbUserLinks: Array<UserLinkDB> = await findDBUserLinks(dbUser.user_id);

    const domainUserLinks: Array<UserLinkDomain> = convertToUserLinks(dbUserLinks);

    domainUser.links = domainUserLinks;

    return domainUser;
  });

  return domainUsers;
}
```

Comment: Again, that returns an array of promises *not* a promise of an array. If it returned a promise `Promise.all` wouldn't work on it. That's even what you've declared `domainUsers` as, but isn't the return type; this wouldn't pass type checking.