# NodeJS sending response before running the await methods

Tags: node.js

My NodeJS controller is sending the response before finish running the wait methods.

The response with the 'OK' message is immediately send back to the client (browser) when I run it. It sends the response before running all the methods.

```
try {
   const ep = await new keysModel().getKeys(); // key is a list of objects
   await ep.map( async (key) => {
      // some operations with the keys here
      // call a fetch to a third party API
      await fetch(urlRequest, {
         method: 'post',
         body:    JSON.stringify(myJSONObject),
         headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Basic ${base64.encode(`${key.APIKey}:${key.PasswordKey}`)}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
      })
      .then(async res => res.json())
      .then(async json => {
         // Here I have some operations with the json response data
         // It includes some database queries
      })
      .catch(async err => {
         // await method to send me an email
         res.status(501).send('error');
      });
   });
   res.status(202).send('OK');
} catch() {
   // await method to send me an email
   res.status(501).send('error');
}
```

Below is the route:

```
const express =  require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/myPath', myController.testMethod);
```

I'm new with NodeJS. Trying to understand how it works.

Thanks

Comment: Could you include the whole function please?

Comment: Inside the then() methods? I just have database requests and math operations

Comment: The function this code is inside.

Comment: you need promise all await Promise.all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map

Comment: @Nonik, could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Sintuz, this code is inside a ```exports.testMethod = async (req, res, next)```

Comment: Maybe `await Promise.all` will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map

Comment: @alex-bu-89 yes, perfect. Thank you. If you want to post it as answer, I can accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) should work, eg. [use async await with array map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map) :)

```
try {
   const ep = await new keysModel().getKeys(); // key is a list of objects
   await Promise.all(ep.map(async (key) => {
      // some operations with the keys here
      // call a fetch to a third party API
      return fetch(urlRequest, {
         method: 'post',
         body:    JSON.stringify(myJSONObject),
         headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Basic ${base64.encode(`${key.APIKey}:${key.PasswordKey}`)}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
      })
      .then(async res => res.json())
      .then(async json => {
         // Here I have some operations with the json response data
         // It includes some database queries
      })
      .catch(async err => {
         // await method to send me an email
         res.status(501).send('error');
      });
   }));
   res.status(202).send('OK');
} catch() {
   // await method to send me an email
   res.status(501).send('error');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, map is not async function, using `async` on map's call back would not be asynced.
you can use one of `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled`, `Promise.any`, `Promise.race` (depends on your needs, please read more about Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

short example for your case, i will use `Promise.all` for the example.

```
try {
    const ep = await new keysModel().getKeys(); // key is a list of objects
    Promise.all(
      ep.map((key) => {
      // some operations with the keys here
      // call a fetch to a third party API
      fetch(urlRequest, {
         method: 'post',
         body:    JSON.stringify(myJSONObject),
         headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Basic 
            ${base64.encode(`${key.APIKey}:${key.PasswordKey}`)}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
      })
      .then(/* Handle array of responses */)
      .catch(/* Handle errors */);
  );
  // proceed..
  } catch() {
  // await method to send me an email
  res.status(501).send('error');
}
```