# How to execute method after all forEach loop completed using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am facing one issue. I need to execute one method after all nested `forEach` completed using node.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
let jsonArr = _.get(req, ['body', 'test_suite']);
jsonArr.forEach(async ele => {
     let stepsArr = ele.steps;
     let devices = ele.devices;
     let deviceArr = devices.split(',');
     let arr = [];
     deviceArr.forEach(e => {
        arr.push({ 'name': e });
     })
      ele.devices = '';
      ele.devices = arr;
      stepsArr.forEach(async el => {
           if (el.operation === 'PATCH' || el.operation === 'PUT' || el.operation === 'POST') {
                        if (el.attachments && el.attachments[0].content === '') {
                            fileFlag = false;
                            msg = '_id is mandotary for POST/PATCH/PUT operation.';
                        } else {
                            const cid = el.attachments[0].content;
                            const result = await findById(cid, 'useCaseFile');
                            if (result.status === 1 && !_.isEmpty(result.data)) {
                                const contentToBase64 = result.data.fileData;
                                el.attachments[0].content = '';
                                el.attachments[0].content = contentToBase64;
                            }
                     }
             } 
        })
 })

console.log('jsonArr', jsonArr)
let originalJSON = {};
originalJSON['test_suite'] = jsonArr;
originalJSON['schema'] = "hello";
originalJSON['version'] = 10;
await downloadFiles(res, originalJSON, 1);
```

So here I need after finishing the nested loop execution then the `console` message should print and also `downloadFiles` method should invoke. But as per my code before finishing loop execution `console.log` is executing and also `downloadFiles` method is invoking as result I am not getting the right result. Here I need after finishing the all nested loop execution the stuffs below `console` message should execute.

Comment: Use `Promise.all` instead

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map