# using async await with map does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, async-await, promise

Lets say that I have this code:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3]

let counter = 0

array.map(async (item) => {
  console.log(await item, ++counter)
  console.log(await item, ++counter)
})
```

the expected output would be

```
1, 1
1, 2
2, 3
2, 4
3, 5
3, 6
```

but what I am getting is this

```
1, 1
2, 2
3, 3
1, 4
2, 5
3, 6
```

it seems like the first `await` call is running first for the whole array, then the second one in being run, why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you expect the initial output?

Comment: And why would you need to `await` a number?

Comment: it is just part of a bigger problem simplified @Pointy

Comment: It's simplified to the point of not being useful.

Comment: What happens if you take away the `await`? When you try to "simplify" a problem involving behavior you don't understand, it's always risky because the mystery may lie in parts of your code that you  don't expect.

Comment: @Pointy, if the `await` was removed it would work as expected, you are completely right but I am trying to understand this behavior as it is.

Comment: Async functions pause at `await`. That's the entirety of the explanation about your question. But is it really useful to solve your problem? You most likely shouldn't be using an async in a `.map()`. Unless you put that in a `Promise.all()`

Comment: Right, the basic array functions don't understand `async` callbacks. The `.map()` call will just build an array of Promise objects.

Comment: @VLAZ, even if it pauses shouldn't it result to the expected output?

Comment: @Pointy yes it would, but why I am getting this output thought?

Comment: If you want to understand your output, you might want to read up on what microtasks are -> https://javascript.info/event-loop , on a side note async / await on a map/foreach/reduce etc, generally doesn't make much sense.

Comment: pause means the function stops and the next thing in the queue continues. Which is the next function. So you get: start 1 -> pause 1 -> start 2 -> pause 2 -> start 3 -> pause 3 -> resume 1 -> pause 1 -> resume 2 -> pause 2 -> resume 3 -> pause 3 -> resume 1 -> finish  1 -> resume 2 -> finish 2 -> resume 3 -> finish 3

Comment: @VLAZ, Aha thank you it is much more clearer now.

Comment: @Keith, thank you I will sure read that.

Comment: @GamesMan except it doesn't really help with any real code. Because you shouldn't write this code to begin with. And your real use-case is probably different.

Comment: @VLAZ, it is different, but this does not nullify this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (hopefully) better illustration. The thing is, `map` doesn't wait for its callback ("mapper") to complete. It just fires it for each element. So, when `map` is done, we end up with N mappers hanging around, each of them waiting for `await` to complete, because `await`, even if used with a non-promise, still means waiting, namely, waiting for the current "execution context" to exit.

```js
const array = ['A', 'B', 'C']

let counter

function item(arg) {
    console.log('    CALLED item', arg, ' => ', counter++)
}

console.log('SYNC: before map')
counter = 0
array.map(async (x) => {
    console.log('  begin SYNC mapper', x)
    item(x);
    console.log('    1st item of', x, 'done')
    item(x);
    console.log('  end SYNC mapper', x)
})
console.log('after map')

console.log('--------------------------')

console.log('ASYNC: before map')
counter = 0
array.map(async (x) => {
    console.log('  begin ASYNC mapper', x)
    await item(x);
    console.log('    1st item of', x, 'done')
    await item(x);
    console.log('  end ASYNC mapper', x)
})
console.log('after map')

console.log('execution context ended')
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Array methods like `map`, `forEach` etc are not await-aware. In other words, they would execute the callback function regardless of the `await` keywords used inside them.

Here is a test:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]

array.map(async (item) => {
  console.log('Immediate Item: ', item);
  console.log('Awaited item', await Promise.resolve(item));
})
```

You can see from the results that all 3 "immediate items" are loged out first and then comes the "awaited" items.

If you need a loop that respects async/await, use `for-of` loop.

```js
async function main() {

  const array = [1, 2, 3]

  for (let item of array) {
          console.log('Immediate Item: ', item);
          console.log('Awaited item', await Promise.resolve(item));
    }

}

main();
```

Answer (score -1):

## Besides the asynchronous part

Don't use `Array.map` as an imperative loop. Use `Array.forEach` instead.

- `Array.map` *transforms* each value (*in any order (!)*).
- `Array.forEach` calls each value in sequential order.

Practically speaking, I guess you could assume sequential execution for `Array.map`, but it is bad practice to do that.

## The asynchronous part

You are expecting `Array.map` to wait for the two `console.log` statements to finish, before calling the next item. This is neither true for `Array.map` or `Array.forEach`, because though the code might *look* sequential, it is asynchronous. And in Jav

If you want to execute asynchronous functions in sequence, there are basically two ways of doing it:

Use `for` loop

```
(async () => {
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    console.log(await array[i], ++counter)
    console.log(await array[i], ++counter)
  }
})()
```

Use `Array.reduce`

```
array.reduce(async (p, item) => {
  await p
  console.log(await item, ++counter)
  console.log(await item, ++counter)
}, Promise.resolve())
```

Comment: It's maybe worth pointing out the `Array.reduce`, creates something called a Promise  chain,.   Were as the for loop doesn't, for very large arrays the for loop would be better, and is more flexible as break / continue also work as expected.