# NODEJS Getting data from database , then use them

Tags: sql, node.js, database, asynchronous, async-await

i want to get data from database and array-loop
That's my actual structure.
I have already test a tons of things without success

```
app.get('/url' async (req,res)=> {
    value = []
    async function myFunction(){
    
        myArray.map(async(data)=> {
            db('MY QUERY')
            .then((res)=> {
                value.push(res)
            })
        })
    }
    await myFunction()
    console.log(value) // Always empty
})
```

I'm open to any tips from you ! :)

EDIT : More information about database connection:
myArray is like : ["a","*","b","myOwnMathFunction(a)"] but not important here
Query : `"SELECT * FROM User WHERE id='1' "` //Verified & work

```
const bd = mysql.createConnection({ MY CONFIG})
    const db =  util.promisify(bdd.query).bind(bdd)
```

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map

Comment: What is your SQL query? And provide some more code related to database connection and all.

Comment: @zx01 My SQL query work & my database connection work too , i only have problem with async notion.
I added more informations on the post

Comment: Yeah I understand but you need to give some context like what is `myArray` here?

Comment: @zx01 that's an array of math operator & maded functions used in my loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `Array#map()` to create multiple promises, e.g. from database queries.
- Use `Promise.all()` to wait for multiple promises.
- Use `try/catch` to handle success and error.

i.e.

```
app.get('/url', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ?';
        const queries = myArray.map((item) => database.query(sql, [item.x, item.y, item.z]));
        const results = await Promise.all(queries);
        res.send(results);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: It work really well , thanks !
I saw this but didn't understand how to use it , thanks for your explanation of  each things

Comment: @Jogoldirus If it works well and you're using it, please tick the answer as "accepted". This will close the thread.