# fetching async await data outside map function in node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, async-await

```js
let object = [{
  id: `01`, name: `fish`, type: `marine`,
}, {
  id: `02`, name: `fish`, type: `fresh`,
}, {
  id: `03`, name: `fish`, type: `tank`,
}, {
  id: `04`, name: `animal`, type: `pet`,
}, {
  id: `05`, name: `animal`, type: `wild`,
}, {
  id: `06`, name: `animal`, type: `zoo`,
}, {
  id: `07`, name: `food`, type: `veg`,
}, {
  id: `08`, name: `food`, type: `non-veg`,
}]

let data = []
object.map((value) => {
  data.push([value.name, value.type])
})

console.log(data)
```

I can fetch data outside the map function in first example but in second second example i can't fetch data

```js
let object = [{
  id: `01`, name: `fish`, type: `marine`,
}, {
  id: `02`, name: `fish`, type: `fresh`,
}, {
  id: `03`, name: `fish`, type: `tank`,
}, {
  id: `04`, name: `animal`, type: `pet`,
}, {
  id: `05`, name: `animal`, type: `wild`,
}, {
  id: `06`, name: `animal`, type: `zoo`,
}, {
  id: `07`, name: `food`, type: `veg`,
}, {
  id: `08`, name: `food`, type: `non-veg`,
}]
    
let data=[];
let test;
object.map(async (value) => {
  test = await getValue(value.name);
  data.push([value.name,value.type,test]);            
})
console.log(data);
```

As in first example i can easily fetch data outside the map function fut in second function I am getting blank array how can i fetch async await data outside map function

- where am i doing wrong i don't get it

Comment: what is `getValue`

Comment: getvalue() is my function which value contain in promise so that's why i am using async await to fetch value @brk

Comment: please share that function also

Comment: that;s a huge code @brk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let object = [{
  id: `01`, name: `fish`, type: `marine`,
}, {
  id: `02`, name: `fish`, type: `fresh`,
}, {
  id: `03`, name: `fish`, type: `tank`,
}, {
  id: `04`, name: `animal`, type: `pet`,
}, {
  id: `05`, name: `animal`, type: `wild`,
}, {
  id: `06`, name: `animal`, type: `zoo`,
}, {
  id: `07`, name: `food`, type: `veg`,
}, {
  id: `08`, name: `food`, type: `non-veg`,
}]
    
async function demo(){
    
 let data=[];
 let test;

 for( const value of object){
   test = await getValue(value.name);
   data.push([value.name,value.type,test]);
 }

 console.log(data);
}
```

Try this I hope this will work as you have to write your code in `for` loop what you are trying to achieve it will work

Answer (score 2):

Note that the map function yields a Promise object as a return value for each item.

And the moment when `data` finishes collecting all the data should come after all the Promises finishes.

So to ensure the procedure finishes, use a `await Promise.all()` before you use the `data`.

```js
let object = [{
  id: `01`, name: `fish`, type: `marine`,
}, {
  id: `02`, name: `fish`, type: `fresh`,
}, {
  id: `03`, name: `fish`, type: `tank`,
}, {
  id: `04`, name: `animal`, type: `pet`,
}, {
  id: `05`, name: `animal`, type: `wild`,
}, {
  id: `06`, name: `animal`, type: `zoo`,
}, {
  id: `07`, name: `food`, type: `veg`,
}, {
  id: `08`, name: `food`, type: `non-veg`,
}]

let data=[];
let test;
let promises = object.map(async (value) => {
  test = await getValue(value.name);
  data.push([value.name,value.type,test]);            
})

// 1. This line matters
await Promise.all(promises);
console.log(data);

// 2. Or if you cannot use await here
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

By the way, because the `getValue` function is asyncronous, so you possibly will got the data in a completely random order, if you care about the order, you may need another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this you will get your response viva for loop easily.
Map function uses a callback function which to be traversed on each element for given array. For more details just go throug this [async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map) for Array.map fuction, can also use the promise.all for the same as mentioned in post in the given link.

```js
let object=
    [
     {
      id:`01`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`marine`,
     },
     {
      id:`02`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`fresh`,
     },
     {
      id:`03`,
      name:`fish`,
      type:`tank`,
     },
     {
      id:`04`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`pet`,
     },
     {
      id:`05`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`wild`,
     },
     {
      id:`06`,
      name:`animal`,
      type:`zoo`,
     },
     {
      id:`07`,
      name:`food`,
      type:`veg`,
     },
     {
      id:`08`,
      name:`food`,
      type:`non-veg`,
     }
    ]

    const getData = async function(){
      let data=[];
      for (var i=0; i<object.length; i++){
        let value = object[i];
        let test= await getValue(value.name);
        data.push([value.name,value.type,test]);  
      }
      return data;
    }

console.log(await getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise.all`:

```js
const data = await Promise.all(object.map(async (value) => {
  const test = await getValue(value.name);
  return [value.name,value.type,test]
}))

console.log(data)
```