# How can I make queries inside a map function async? - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

So I need to make queries using a .map function and then push it to an array and return it but the problem is the array is always empty when returning because its not async, I have tried `async/await` but that does not work. An example of my code would be like this:

```
let arrayToSend = []

anotherArray.map(obj => {
    Model.findOne({_id: id}).exec(function(err, result){
        if (!err) {
           arrayToSend.push(result) 
        } else {
           let anotherObj = {key: value}
           arrayToSend.push(anotherObj) 
        }
    })
}

return res.json({arrayToSend})
```

Comment: You also need `Promise.all` when working with `async`/`await` in `map`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the for…of loop instead of map with the async/await syntax

```
let arrayToSend = []

for(const obj of anotherArray) {
    try {
       const result = await Model.findOne({_id: id}).exec()
       arrayToSend.push(result) 
   catch (err) {
       let anotherObj = {key: value}
       arrayToSend.push(anotherObj) 
   }
}

return res.json({arrayToSend})
```

Comment: This does not work. The array is still empty.

Comment: This should be working according to this documenttion https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/promise
Could you share a little bit more of your code, like the function declaration or the anotherArray init ?

Comment: I got the code working with some other changes! Thanks so much for trying to help me.

Comment: `for` makes the calls *synchronous*.  [LOOK AT THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map#answer-59471024)