# Nuxt page render loop on back navigation

Tags: nuxt.js

I have an issue with two pages. Page 1, is a list, and page 2 detail an item in
the list with a back button. Page 1 loads fine when first accessed, however
after clicking the back button or navigating back there are thousands of
canceled requests in the network tab, and `asyncData` is called thousands of
times until finally there is a memory leak and the server crashes. If I try to navigate from page 2 to page 3 everything works great, if I click the back button to page 2 it works fine.

**Page 1**

```html
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <div>
            <div v-if="appointment" div class="text-center">
                <span class="text-h5">
                    {{ appointment.Representative | upper }}
                </span>
            </div>

            <div v-if="announcements && announcements.length">
                <v-card
                    v-for="announcement in announcements"
                    v-show="announcement.status == 'visible'"
                    :key="announcement._id"
                >
                    <v-card-title>
                        {{ announcement.message }}
                    </v-card-title>
                </v-card>
            </div>
            <v-divider v-else class="mx-5 mt-1" />

            <div>
                <v-row v-for="evt in evts" :key="evt.EvntId" align="center">
                    <v-col>
                        <span> {{ evt | evtTitle }} </span>
                    </v-col>

                    <v-col cols="2" align="end" class="mx-2">
                        <v-btn
                            color="primary"
                            text
                            :disabled="evt.Status.toLowerCase() === 'pending'"
                            nuxt
                            :to="`/event/${evt.EvntId}`"
                        >
                            Open
                        </v-btn>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </div>
        </div>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    async asyncData({ params, $api, $misc }) {
        let appointment = null;
        let events = null;

        const req1 = await $api
            .get(`/public/club/${params.id}/shoot/`)
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });

        appointment = req1.data.find(
            // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq
            (x) => x.ShootId == params.shootId
        );

        const evs = await $api
            .get(`/public/club/${params.id}/shoot/${params.aptId}/evnt/`)
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        events = evs.data;

        const notableEvents = events.filter(
            (x) => x.Status.toLowerCase() === 'active'
        );

        for (let i = 0; i < notableEvents.length; i++) {
            const event = notableEvents[i];
            const x = await $api
                .get(
                    `/public/club/${params.id}/appointment/${params.aptId}/details/evnt/${event.EvntId}`
                )
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                });

            event.Scores = x.data;
            event.allScores = x.data.length;
        }

        return {
            shoot,
            events,
        };
    },
    data() {
        return {
            appointment: null,
            events: [],
            announcements: [],
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

**Page 2**

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-btn @click="goBack"> Back </v-btn>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    goBack(){
      this.$router.go(-1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

Globally I have tried

Disabling prefetch in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
// disable prefetch
router:{
  prefetchLinks: false
},
```

Disabling `keep-alive` on the nuxt view

```html
<nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{ max: 10 }" />
<!-- to -->
<nuxt />
```

In page 1 I have tried disabling prefetch on the links, and on the global level. By replacing `v-btn` with `nuxt-link`

```html
<nuxt-link no-prefetch :to="`/event/${evt.EvntId}`">
    Open
</nuxt-link>
```

I have also tried using `fetch` instead of async data, but it produces the same result.

---

In `page2` I have tried using a full link to the previous page instead with and without `no-prefetch` with the link being generated in the `to` prop, as a computed property, and setting it in `data` on `mounted`.

```html
<nuxt-link no-prefetch :to="`/appointment/${$route.params.appointmentId}/events`">
    Open
</nuxt-link>
```

I am at an absolute loss as to what could be causing this on this pair of pages, only when using the back button or navigating away.

---

**Edit**

I have also tried moving the for loop of subsequent requests out of `asyncData` and moved it to `fetch` the issue still persits.

I have also swapped `asyncData` with `fetch`

I also took all of my promises and turned them into an array and awaited them.

Comment: What is the endpoint being called several times? Also, did you tried to `console.log` and see if each request does it job? A simple solution would be to convert it into a `fetch()` hook and see if you still have the issue. No mixin or alike anywhere?

Comment: All of the endpoints are get called except the request from the loop. Looking at the server the requests are being responded to with status `200`. `fetch()` was leading to other complications with the `notableEvents` loop, sometimes not loading data. I would be happy to go back to that method. No mixins, but there are filters.

Comment: You should probably use map and async/await combo because I guess that `notableEvents.length` is undefined or falsy under some conditions. Check this answer to see how to rewrite it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140562/8816585 (you can of course skip the TS part)

Comment: I tried replacing asyncData with fetch, no luck. I also converted my requests into an array with `await promise.all` and the issue still persists.

Comment: Did you try to replace the for loop with a map tho?