# Is there a way to work with Javascript Promise in following function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

So I have the following piece of code in javascript

```
async function getFoodData (req, res) {
    const ids = req.body.data;
    const food = [];
    ids.map((id) => {
        Food.findOne({ _id: id },(err, result) => {
            if(result){
                food.push(result)
            } 
        })
    })
    return res.status(200).json({ Food: food })
}
```

The ids are a bunch of Mongo Id's received in the body
This function looks for data and on returning results it adds it into the food array. However, the return statement runs first and I get an empty array. I think my problem will be solved by using Promises but I am new to the concept and hence can someone help me with it.

Comment: Read [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map). It is very well explained. If you don't want it look complicated just use for loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to achieve this.

`Promise.all()` takes an array of promises. Now with the statement, `await Promise.all(foodPromises);` you are **waiting** for all the promises to be resolved.

After that you can filter out the result array for only `truthy`   values, which you were doing in your code.

```
async function getFoodData (req, res) {
    const ids = req.body.data;
    const food = [];
    const foodPromises = ids.map((id) => 
        Food.findOne({ _id: id }));
    await Promise.all(foodPromises);
    let returnData = foodPromises.filter(x => x);
    return res.status(200).json({ Food: food })
}
```

`.map()` is usually used when you want to transform an array into another. If you just want to run a loop use `for`/`forEach()`.

Comment: @Nishanktiwari17 no worries. Please mark the answer as accepted to complete the question

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I also found another solution

```
async function getFoodData (req, res) {
    const ids = req.body.data;
    const food = [];
    async function foodData(id) {
        const food = await Food.findOne({ _id: id })
            if(food) return food
    } 
    for( let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ ) {
        const result = await foodData(ids[i])
        if(result) food.push(result)
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ Food: food })
}
```

Creating a function and then using await while looping did the work for me