# Fetch data trough a computed function in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In `event.agents` I've plain text ID's stored, which I want to fetch do get the specific data. I wrote a computed function to fetch the data, but my backend server always crashes through this way.

CastError

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"

So, I guess I have to work with Promise somehow. But I don't know how.

The idea is to display the required agent data e.g. like this:

```html
<p>{{ getAgent(agent).first_name }}</p>
```

Is it even possible like that?

```html
<div v-for="agent in event.agents" :key="agent.id">
  <p>{{ getAgent(agent) }}</p>
</div>
```

```js
computed: {
  getAgent(agentID) {
    const agent = this.fetchAgentData(agentID)
    return agent
  }
}

// I tried it with async/await, but eslint tells me 'no-async-in-computed-properties'
```

```js
async fetchAgentData(agentID) {
  try {
    const agent = await this.$axios.$get(`/api/get-specific-agent/${agentID}`)

    if (agent.success) {
      return agent.data
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
},
```

Comment: Looks like you have to pass `agent.id` instead of whole `agent` object in `fetchAgentData` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computed` are not meant to be used with side effects. It's goal is to have a result based on some other variables, here you're calling a method with an HTTP call, I thought you would get a side-effect ESlint warning here too, but it's kinda avoiding it.
Also, a computed does not take a param as [seen here](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#computed), it's mainly
`key + function` hence `getAgent: { ...` in your case.

There is no possibility to have several computed with their own state, you can only have one single value for a given computed.

What you're looking for here is mainly a casual `method`, nothing else.

If you want to handle some performance concerns, you can use a memoization on it to not run avoidable HTTP calls etc, [like that](https://www.maxpou.fr/vuejs-performance-improvement-with-memoization). Not sure that it's worth the trouble in your case tho.

Overall, I'm not sure if you need to even run it per-element, using a single [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to populate all of your `event.agent` ahead of time is probably the simplest way here.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to find another solution based on my last question. Apparently this is the wrong way again... [Replace objects with nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145512/replace-objects-within-nested-array)