# Api call data update in React hook is not working, It's not updating the state

Tags: reactjs

[![

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import axios from "axios";
export const getPokemanData = async () => {
    let arr = [];
    const list = await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/');
    const d = list.data.results;
    const data = d.map(async (item, index) => {
        arr[index] = {
            'name': item.name
        };
        const d = await axios.get((item.url));
        const q = d.data.abilities.map(item => item.ability.name);
        arr[index]['ability'] = q.join(",");
        return arr;
    });
    
    return arr;
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Leh.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Leh.jpg)

The snippet code which is added in image and this above code for API call. Api is working properly but the value getting update in UI is only for name not for Ability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, async await is not working in map of array
you can promisify your array by using Promise.all

here you can see what I say :

[Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map)

Comment: I tried many approaches. But if you see the snippet code for UI in attached. In data I am getting only one value name but in console both value are coming.

Comment: I tried this approach it's working, Thanks :)