# How to wait for a async function before run the other one

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, nuxt.js

there is 2 methods, I want to push data to database when the method getDownloadUrl finishes to push all urls to array

```
    async getDownloadUrl(newCardData) {
      const cardImagesRef = await this.$fire.storage
        .ref('/albums_cards/')
        .child(uuidV1())
      this.newCard.cardImages.forEach(async (image) => {
        const imageRef = cardImagesRef.child(uuidV4())
        await imageRef.put(image)
        const url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL()
        newCardData.images.push(url)
      })
    },

    async postNewCard() {
      this.newCard.loading = true

      const newCardData = {
        title: this.newCard.cardTitle,
        description: this.newCard.cardSnippet,
        images: [],
      }

      await this.getDownloadUrl(newCardData)
      await this.$fire.database.ref('albums/cards').push(newCardData)
      this.newCard.loading = false
      this.newCard.cardTitle = null
      this.newCard.cardSnippet = null
      this.newCard.cardImages = []
      this.newCard.cardImageUrls = []
    },
```

Comment: Your code should work well. Maybe it just takes time to record into the DB?

Comment: it is uploading an empty array of images where should be array of urls, @kissu

Comment: urls can not get in time to be generate, I want to wait for urls and then upload @kissu

Comment: Oh, you maybe need an `await Promise.all`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140562/8816585

Comment: @kissu You mean like this:                                                                                                    
        await Promise.all(
        this.newCard.cardImages?.forEach(async (image) => {
          const imageRef = cardImagesRef.child(uuidV4())
          await imageRef.put(image)
          await imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => urls.push(url))
        })
      )

Comment: but I am getting error:  undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) @kissu

Comment: Use `.map` rather + `async/await` without `.then`.

Comment: Oh, Thank you a lot bruh. Finally I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP fixed the issue thanks to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140562/8816585).
So mainly using:

- `await Promise.all`
- `async + await`
- `.map`
- and by removing `.then`