# Error messages about using the await keyword within an async function

Tags: next.js

In my NextJS API route, I have the following (simplified) code and a few error messages show up:

```js
// /app/api/tacos/route.js
export async function GET(request) {
  const data = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}];

  try {
   data.map((item, index) => {
      await myAsyncFunction();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
};

const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  console.log('myAsyncFunction');
};
```

In VSCode, when I roll-over the word `await`, I see the following error message:

> 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308)
> route.js(107, 18): Did you mean to mark this function as 'async'?

When I run the app, I (often) see the app break and then I see this error:

> Error:
> X - await isn't allowed in non-async function

The top-level function has an `async` keyword but I am getting error messages about using the `await` keyword.  I thought that this allows for the `await` keyword to be used throughout the function?  Is this not the case?  How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do not add "solved" to the title of the question. After a while you will be able to accept the answer (checkmark) to signal that you regard this as the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that the `async` keyword allows for the `await` within the body of the function but that `await` must directly be in the body of that function.  But children function, with the `await` keyword, must also be marked `async`.

On the flip side though, if you have multiple layers of functions (children function within children function within children function) - you only need the `async` keyword to wrap the functions that contain the `await` keyword.

So, if you have 5 layers of function and only the 5th function contains an `await` keyword within it, then only that 5th function needs to be marked `async`.

```
const myFirstFunction = () => {
  const mySecondFunction = () => {
    const myThirdFunction = () => { 
      const myFourthFunction = () => {
          const myFifthFunction = async () => {
              await myAsyncFunction();
          }
          myFifthFunction();
      }
      myFourthFunction();
    }
    myThirdFunction();
  }
  mySecondFunction();
}

const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  console.log('myAsyncFunction was run');
};

myFirstFunction();
```

---

So there are multiple levels of answer to your question:

To "get rid of the red squiggly lines", you need to add the `async` keyword so something like this:

```
data.map(async (item, index) => {
  await myAsyncFunction();
}
```

And that will be generally fine for the `myAsyncFunction` that you defined in your question.  However, your if you made that slightly more complex and had it return a value in addition to doing the logging then you'd quickly realize you need just one more step.

```
const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  console.log('console_myAsyncFunction');
  return 'returned_value_myAsyncFunction';
};
```

If you run your code and look at the returned values, you realize it returns 3x Promises and not 3x 'returned_value_myAsyncFunction'.  And if you made the mistake of just putting an `await` in front of the `data.map()`, it would not work as expected because `await` expects a Promise, not an Array that contains Promises, which is what you get from the `data.map(async (item,index) => ...`

```
// /app/api/tacos/route.js
export async function GET(request) {
  const data = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}];

  try {
   await Promise.all(data.map(async (item, index) => {
      await myAsyncFunction();
    }))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
};

const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  console.log('myAsyncFunction');
};

await GET();
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map/71970498#71970498) and [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59471024/943087) which shows how `.map()` returns an array in the proper order after `await Promise.all`

---

You didn't ask about this specifically, but let's talk about the `.map()` function.

Coming to React from a different programming language and seeing the `.map` used so frequently, it may seem that `.map` is the way that JavaScript handles iterating through arrays.

But when looking at the MDN docs, you can see the following:

> Since map builds a new array, calling it without using the returned array is an anti-pattern; use forEach or for...of instead.

Well, it turns out, that the `.map` you so often see in React components within JSX content (within the return statement) was just part of an expression that does in fact return a NEW array with html outputs for each item of the array.  And those outputs that you likely saw were something like ... `(item,i) => (<div>{item.somethingInteresting}</div>)`.

---

Ah okay, then let's look at alternatives to `.map()`.

Doing a little more digging and saw this informal speed test of different loops [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939755/943087).  It seems speed-wise, they are pretty different. (Bigger is better):

- `forEach` => x1.27 speed of `.map()`
- `for...of`  => x5.446 speed of `.map()`
- `for loop` => x43.2 speed of `.map()`

And since `for...of` is newer (EMCAScript 2015 / ES6) vs. the `forEach` (EMCAScript 2009 / ES 5), I think I'll stick to the faster/newer `for...of` when I need that syntactic sugar and use the `for loop` when I don't.

Okay, so let's see how to use the `await` for these two.

```
// # for loop
// /app/api/tacos/route.js
export async function GET(request) {
async function GET(request) {
  const data = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]

  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       await myAsyncFunction();
    }      
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  console.log('myAsyncFunction');
};
await GET();
```

```
// # for...of
// /app/api/tacos/route.js
export async function GET(request) {
  const data = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]

  try {
    for (const i of data) {
       await myAsyncFunction();
    }      
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  console.log('myAsyncFunction');
};
await GET();
```

More details on loops [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/943087)

Side note: It is worth noting that these loops wait for the full execution of each iteration of the code block to finish (with the `await`) before the next iteration takes place.  In contrast, the `.map()` kicks off all the functions at once, and then the `await Promise.all` waits for all the Promises to resolve or reject.

Comment: If this is the answer, please mark it as the solution to your question!